# sqlalchemy query to fetch latest data for a foreign key (parent) combination

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have some models that have some parent classes with a leaf node class called Measurement, which gets updated every second with new data.

I want to fetch the new data from another db connection and update a display periodically.

At the moment I query the root parent, then iterate over the ORM relationship lists (Measurement is dynamically loaded).  When I get to Measurement I tried using `value = parent.measurements[-1].value` but that was very slow.  I assume everything is read into the list before slicing.

I changed the code to an explicit query which made it faster.  e.g. `value = parent.measurements.order_by( Measurement.id.desc() ).first().value`

**With SQLAlchemy, how can I get all the latest measurements for each parent class combination in with one SQL transaction?**

I'm assuming some kind of join/filter (or maybe a view) is the answer?

Here is a sample class model below.  Say I have the DB populated with 2 collectors, 3 devices per collector, with 4 ADCs per device.

**With SQLAlchemy, how can I get all the latest measurements for each adc of each device of each collector, with one SQL transaction?**

```py
class Collector( Model ) :
    __tablename__   = 'collector'
    id              = Column( Integer, primary_key=True )
    #! --- Relationships ---
    devices         = relationship( 'Device', back_populates='collector' )


class Device( Model ) :
    __tablename__   = 'device'
    id              = Column( Integer, primary_key=True )
    collector_id    = Column( Integer, ForeignKey( 'collector.id' ) )
    #! --- Relationships ---
    collector       = relationship( 'Collector', back_populates='devices', uselist=False )
    adcs            = relationship( 'ADC', back_populates='device' )


class ADC( Model ) :
    __tablename__   = 'adc'
    id              = Column( Integer, primary_key=True )
    channel         = Column( Integer )
    device_id       = Column( Integer, ForeignKey( 'device.id' ) )
    #! --- Relationships ---
    device          = relationship( 'Device', back_populates='adcs', uselist=False )
    measurements    = relationship( 'Measurement', back_populates='adc', lazy='dynamic' )


class Measurement( Model ) :
    __tablename__   = 'measurement'
    id              = Column( Integer, primary_key=True )
    timestamp       = Column( DateTime, nullable=False )
    value           = Column( Integer, nullable=False )
    adc_id          = Column( Integer, ForeignKey( 'adc.id' ) )
    #! --- Relationships ---
    adc             = relationship( 'ADC', back_populates='measurements', uselist=False )
```

Comment: What result do you want?  Is a list of the latest `Measurement` objects enough?

Comment: Yes - lets ignore the Collector - I want to do 2 things.  (1) obtain a list of the latest Measurements - for each ADC channel for each Device.  (2) obtain a list of latest Measurements, for each ADC, for a specified Device.  I can probably work out any other variation once I can achieve those 2 outcomes.  A bonus would be how to make this a database "view"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem using hybrid properties.

```py
class ADC( Model ) :
   ...
    @hybrid_property
    def latest_measurement( self ) -> float :
        measurement = self.measurements.order_by( Measurement.id.desc() ).first()
        return measurement
```

and then something like:

```py
    collector = session.query( Collector )
    for device in collector.devices :
        for adc in device.adcs :
            measurement = adc.latest_measurement
            do_something( measurement )
```

Still there is probably another way of doing this (perhaps with hybrid methods on the Measurements model and passing in match criteria as arguments and doing a few `.filter()` calls ?)